# Have any international organizations negotiated with Iran about ceasing their weapon supply to the Houthi?

Tags: iran, piracy, houthi-movement, terror

After a recent attack, in which a Norwegian-owned ship heading to Italy got attacked by Houthi missiles ([aljazeera](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/12/12/tanker-attacked-by-cruise-missile-as-it-traverses-bab-el-mandeb-strait))
I am curious if there were any efforts from international organizations to resolve the matters diplomatically and negotiate with Iran, as to resolve the issue of their weapon supply to the Houthi, to make international waters safer? ([VOA](https://www.voanews.com/a/uk-presents-evidence-linking-iran-in-houthi-weapon-supply/6961928.html))

Comment: You need to provide a link between the Houthi attack and Iran - e.g., did they use Iranian-made rockets? Or at least a reference to Iran being their main supporter/enabler.

Comment: While Iran claims that all missiles are made by the Houthis, does the negotiation have any meaning?

Comment: What would the negotiations look like? Iran wants the US embargoes lifted, among other things. Which "international organizations" can convince the US to do that, to have some role in such negotiations? Also, Iran themselves have been attacking ships in a similar fashion. Related Q: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/83045/why-are-there-so-few-reactions-to-the-houthis-attacks-on-ships

Comment: Letting aside the difficulties of proving Iran is to blame, who would you expect to negotiate with Iran?  Since the JCPOA was terminated Iran has cuddled up to Russia and the West has little leverage on it - not sure what sanctions remain undone, for example.  Russia loves the Gaza mess, distracts everyone from Ukraine.  The ships attacked are, IIRC, so far somewhat Western-affiliated and the rest of the world isn't supportive of Western support - such as it is - for Israel.  I guess China has some influence, but why should other countries stick their neck out?  Does the UN have leverage?